# Modify privacy settings for Album

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, acl, privacy

I've been searching in a lot of places about modifying the privacy settings for an album, thing that can't be done through GRAPH API; as far as I know.

I would like to know if something has changed in the GRAPH API to allow me to modify the privacy settings (since the posts that I've read are quite old) or at least if there is some workaround (deleting and recreating the album with a new set of permissions would be a good idea?).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, unfortunately for your use-case there's no API for changing privacy settings on an object retroactively.